# What is the OpenGl format of Bitmap.getPixels() in Android?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

`Bitmap.getPixels()` returns an integer array, with pixel values returned in a "Packed Integer" format, described in the documentation for `Color`.

This format is A, R, G, B.

I want to pass this array to `GLES10.glTexImage2D()`. I have tried specifying both `internalFormat` and `format` as `GL_RGBA`. But this causes the the Blue and Red channels to be swapped.

I couldn't find an Opengl equivalent which describes this format.

---

Aside, I can swap the R and B channels using bitwise operations to conform to GL_RGBA, but would rather prefer if OpenGl could recognize the format natively.

---

**Update:**
I know I can use the Bitmap directly with `TexImage2D()`, but I need to call `getPixels()` because I need to manipulate the pixel data before using it as a texture. I can convert the pixels back to a Bitmap, but like I said, I would prefer if I could use the pixels directly as a texture.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to retrieve the pixels, nor to deal with the underlying pixel formats, just pass the Bitmap object to the [GLUtils.texImage2D()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLUtils.html#texImage2D%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int%29) utility.

eg:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(...);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, this works, and that was my original code. But I need two bitmaps derived from this Bitmap, and they were leaking memory (there's a well known bug in Android). Hence, this solution.

Comment: I take that back.. I was able to find that the bitmaps weren't actually leaking memory. The culprits were a couple of direct buffers which the activity had allocated and was holding onto them between activity restarts. I explicitly set them to null and all is fine now. My final solution uses int[] data for TexImage2D as that is more optimal in my case.

Comment: Good! But, I don't see any texImage2D() variant which accepts int[] data.. What do you mean?

Comment: @oliverg You are right, there isn't one. I meant the one which accepts a Buffer. The Buffer basically wraps the int[] with very little overhead.

Comment: I see.. Well, actually, if you're not afraid of native code, then you could take a look at the jnigraphics library available as of Froyo. It allows to modify Bitmap pixels data in-place.